# \nocite{*} problem using moderncv with multibib

Tags: citing, subdividing, moderncv, multibib

I am recently using the `moderncv` template with `multibib` package for writing my cv.
The problem that I encounter is as the following:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} 
\moderncvstyle{casual}  
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\usepackage{multibib}
\newcites{j}{Journals}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\section{Publications}
\nocitej{wang2012}
\bibliographystylej{plain}
\bibliographyj{publications}
\end{document}
```

When I try to compile BiBTeX first, it also shows the error message:
"Process exited with error(s)" and nothing else....

I do this on a Windows7 system, any suggestions?
If not using the multibib package, everything works out fine, which means:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} 
\moderncvstyle{casual}  
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
%\usepackage{multibib}
%\newcites{j}{Journals}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{publications}
\end{document}
```

Comment: My suggestion would be to use `biblatex` instead of `multibib`. I think it is more convenient. But I don't know if that is an option for you.

Comment: I just tried your MWE and it works perfectly on my system. Make sure i) you are using a sufficiently recent version of moderncv (support for multi bib was added in v.0.8, of May 24, 2010) and ii) you are calling BiBTeX correctly, i.e. `bibtex j` (`bibtex publications` might call the dummy bibliography file provided with moderncv, which does not has a reference for `wang2012`)

Comment: @Xavier~ To your first question, I've just re-downloaded the latest version of moderncv (v1.0). For the second one, I don't quite get what you mean... the bibtex j is simply like a key for the \newcites, which shouldn't have anything related to the publications.bib file? cuz the publications.bib file is simply the storage of the references. Or am I misunderstood any of them? Thanks.

Comment: I found the solutions!! how weird!!!  I'll have to open up the followings manually and run them, for example: template.tex --> template.aux --> j.aux, could this be some kind of bug? (I don't really know why and how these happens...) Below is the solution that I found somewhere else for your reference: [click here](https://answers.launchpad.net/moderncv/+question/164989)

Comment: We'd like to keep answers separate from questions, so you should write a separate answer instead of editing your answer into the question. Self-answers are perfectly admissible, and a well-written answer may earn you additional reputation.

Comment: @lockstep oh~ sorry, still quite new to do the asking and answering. Thanks for the advice!  ;-)

Comment: @Taco You need to run `bibtex` on `j.aux`, i.e. `bibtex j` as I wrote above. When you use `multibib`, you need to run `bibtex` on every bibliography category you create. This has nothing to do with `moderncv`, this is simply how `multibib` works.

Comment: @Xavier OH!! so that's what you meant!  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Solutions are as below:

The compiling process in TeXmaker should be the following steps:

1. `template.tex` (compile the bibtex first --> Quick Build) -->
2. `j.aux` (open up in TeXmaker --> 
   Compile with `bibtex` (and check if process existed normally)) --> 
   Back to step 1. And do it again, should work!!

(Though may have some error messages occur, 
it works fine and produce a PDF file successfully!)

Comment: It didn't work for me. The seconf bibfile citations are not appearing at all.

Answer (score 0):

I compile in this way without errors, with `multibib` and `\cite{}` commands inside my .tex file for references too:

1. compile **1 time** with *XeLaTeX*
2. **1 time** *BibTeX* (using `bibtex`, not `biber`, in Texmaker config)
3. compile **2 times** with *XeLaTeX*